# a better way to color many individual markers in a scatter chart?

Tags: highcharts

Friends,
My intention is to create an interactive chart that represents a portion of the table of isotopes, which you can see here, for example: http://www.nndc.bnl.gov/chart/.

So: I have a 2-d graph with ~400 points. I want to color code the points after they're drawn according to the value of a piece of metadata I've included for each point. I might have ten shades of red, for example, and set it according to where the point's metadata value falls.

As a test, I've tried to just color them all red, just to get the function call right.

This is my problem: I've figured out how to do this using this code (placed in the chart load event):

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.series[0].data.length; i++) {
                    this.series[1].points[i].update({
                        marker: {
                            fillColor: "#FF0000"
                        }
                    });
```

But I have found that using series.points.update() is *very very* slow.

I've tried to access the marker property directly. I guess first from the API that I could write:
    *series[i].data[j].marker.fillColor="#FF0000"*

or maybe, judging by a bit of code I found in highcharts-more.js:
    *series[i].data[j].markerOptions.fillColor="#FF0000"*

But I see now that the API lists direct calls to marker under 'initial configuration options', and there is no direct call under  'methods and properties'.

My question then: is there a fast way to set the marker color for hundreds of points after the chart is drawn? Or can I somehow change it faster before the chart is drawn?

For what it's worth, my code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/mattmcg/bn35f/13/
Very long, but the relevant parts are right in lines 5-14.

thanks!

Comment: And, I might add, if anybody has any useful ideas of how this project might be easier accomplished, please fire away! I thought of drawing them as stacked column ranges instead of the scatter plot, for example. This is my first experience with highcharts (and I'm not a programmer) so your criticism is very helpful!

Comment: Why not set the color property for each entry in your series.data array? http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data.color

Comment: hi cfs: I've had a hard time getting the scatter plot to work without using markers and *their* color. When I disable markers with a scatter plot, the points don't render, and so changing their color isn't helpful. Odd, isn't it?

Comment: well yes, the marker *IS* the point, so if you disable a scatter plot's markers, you disable the scatter plot, essentially.  But you don't need to disable markers in order to individually color the markers, you simply supply the color information in the data object for each point.

Comment: thanks, that's true: I could have the data array embed the marker colors. That's a sort of last resort, though, because it's also useful to do it programmatically from the resulting page (for example, to view the chart with and without that visual layer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is related to the fact that each call to update() redraws the chart. It would be better to disable redraw (false parameter).

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.update()

Comment: Sebastian, I see now that it's possible to add that 'false' parameter to 'update'. thanks! that takes it from several minutes to 8 seconds. Not a bad improvement!

Answer (score 4):

I would specify the color directly in the data object for each point rather than updating after it is rendered.

You can send anything that can be specified in the plotOptions as a parameter in the point object, as such:

```
data:[{x:0,y:10,marker:{fillColor:'rgba(255,0,0,.5)'}},{x:10,y:25,marker:{fillColor:'rgba(255,0,0,.75)'}},{x:25,y:30,marker:{fillColor:'rgba(255,0,0,.25)'}}]
```

Etc...